# Encoding a string from php to javascript returns errors

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert a PHP EOT string into a js code and I need to encode it since it has some `\n` in it. I can't do it with a simple `jsonencode` because it returns the code with `"`'s and I don't need them there.

So i tried those two approaches which both return an error:

```
<?php
$string = $v['survey'];
function escapeJavaScriptText($string)
{
    return str_replace("\n", '\n', str_replace('"', '\"', addcslashes(str_replace("\r", '', (string)$string), "\0..\37'\\")));
}
?>

<?php echo escapeJavaScriptText(); ?>
```

I've also tried:

```
<?php
$string = $v['survey'];
function javascript_escape($string) {
    $new_str = '';

    $str_len = strlen($string);
    for($i = 0; $i < $str_len; $i++) {
        $new_str .= '\\x' . sprintf('%02x', ord(substr($string, $i, 1)));
    }

    return $new_str;
}
?>

<?php echo javascript_escape(); ?>
```

Both return:
`Missing argument 1 for escapeJavaScriptText()` and `Undefined variable: string in`
But `<?php echo $string; ?>` returns the code I need (just without the encoding).

What am I missing?

Comment: `<?php echo javascript_escape(); ?>` is not passing in `$string`, so `$string` in your function is undefined/out of scope. Either `<?php echo javascript_escape($string); ?>` or `function javascript_escape() { global $string;`

Comment: Oh, I really missed that! It works now but it seems it didn't solve my issue with javascript encoding... http://take.ms/57aXU

Comment: I got it solved by replacing `str_replace('"', '\"'` to `str_replace('"', '"'`.
Thanks!

Comment: You're are replacing a double quote with a double quote?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = $v['survey'];
function javascript_escape($string) {
$new_str = '';
$str_len = strlen($string);
for($i = 0; $i < $str_len; $i++) {
    $new_str .= '\\x' . sprintf('%02x', ord(substr($string, $i,      1)));
 }
return $new_str;
 }
 ?>
 <?php echo javascript_escape($string); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of different variable scopes within your function and global code. In PHP, by default, functions don't have access to global variables.

In your case, variable `$string`, you're trying to use by function `javascript_escape`, is a global variable. So, you have a few ways to avoid `Undefined Variable` exception.

**1. Use "global" keyword to have acces to global variables inside the function.**

After function definition, you just need to specify global variables this way (and remove `$string` from arguments list):

```
function javascript_escape() {
    global $string;

    $new_str = '';

    $str_len = strlen($string);
    for($i = 0; $i < $str_len; $i++) {
        $new_str .= '\\x' . sprintf('%02x', ord(substr($string, $i, 1)));
    }

    return $new_str;
}
```

or

```
function escapeJavaScriptText()
{
    global $string;
    return str_replace("\n", '\n', str_replace('"', '\"', addcslashes(str_replace("\r", '', (string)$string), "\0..\37'\\")));
}
```

**2. Pass `$string` as an argument of function call.**

If you have a reasons not to use global variables at all, you're able to pass unescaped string each time the function has to be called.

```
<?php echo javascript_escape($string); ?>
```

**3. Use pre-escaped string.**

If you have to use `$string` encoded by your function multiple times, it'd be a good practice to escape the variable at the beginning of your code and use it without calling escape function every time you need to use this variable:

```
$escaped_string = javascript_escape($string);

...

<?php echo $escaped_string; ?>
```

Also, I recommend you to read the official documentation about variable scopes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php